# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am using emoji filter, I am getting error that **"Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"**.

**Errro is:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
        at g.<anonymous> (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/emoji.min.js:1:10531)
        at e (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/angular.min.js:155:305)
        at Ia.| (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/angular.min.js:143:248)
        at Object.A.constant [as get] (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/angular.min.js:154:212)
        at g.$digest (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/angular.min.js:98:307)
        at g.$apply (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/angular.min.js:101:157)
        at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/angular.min.js:177:65)
        at HTMLAnchorElement.m.event.dispatch (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/jquery.min.js:3:8436)
        at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web_UI/js/jquery.min.js:3:5146)
```

**Html code:**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="n in q.answers"  ng-bind-html = " n | emoji">
```

json response:

```
{
    "data":[
            {
                "id":10,
                "title":"what is internet?",
                "userID":2,
                "question":"what is internet?",
                "viewed":0,
                "votes":5,
                "answers":[
                            {"id":15,
                            "questionID":10,
                            "userID":2,
                            "answer":"search on google ....:)",
                            "correct":"0",
                            "votes":7

                            },
                            {
                                "id":47,
                                "questionID":10,
                                "userID":2,
                                "answer":"test :smiley:",
                                "correct":"0","votes":0,
                           }
                    ]}
            ]
        }
```

js function:

```
QAApp.controller('askbyctrl', function ($scope, $http){
            $http.get(server + 'api').success(function(data) {
            /*console.log(data);*/
            $scope.qa = data;
          });
          $scope.select = function(item) {
            /*console.log(item);*/
            $scope.selected = item
          }
          $scope.isSelected = function(item) {
            return $scope.selected == item
          }
      });
```

then in html for answer use **ng-repeat="q in qa.data"** and to display answer use **n in q.answers"**

Please tell me how can I solve it?

> [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LX0jH7s0z9Ee8Z5TUSuW)

Comment: the object which is calling 'replace' function is undefined. I think you are assuming it as STRING. Please check that object. error will be solved

Comment: Are there any _null/undefined_ entries on the `q.answers` list? If yes, try filtering out those entries with `ng-repeat="n in q.answers | filter: '!!'"`.

Comment: no their is no any null/undefined entries. I have a demo code which is working, i don't know why it is not working here.....

Comment: Can you provide the JSON for the `q.answers`?

Comment: I send please check....

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ng-bind-html = "n.answer | emoji"`? "n" is an object, not a String.

Comment: <li ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-bind-html="message | emoji"></li> but this is working..... I am not apply emoji filter on n.answer ...please see the html code..

Comment: That's because `messages` is an array of strings while your `answers` is an array of Objects.

Comment: yes I got it....so you have any solution how can I use emoji filter in my code

Comment: I created a plunker, pls edit it accordingly to describe your prob..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the emoji filter to a string, however your `n in q.answers` is looping through a list of objects (not strings). You need to change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="n in q.answers"  ng-bind-html = "n.answer | emoji">
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gNAKAZIBnJ3mrwwJdMMv?p=preview).

Comment: Good! If that's the case, please mark the answer as correct, for future references :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the working code...

```
            angular.module("app", ['emoji', 'ngSanitize']).controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.messages = [
                "Animals: :dog: :cat: :snake:",
                "People: :smile: :confused: :angry:",
                "Places: :house: :school: :hotel:"
            ];
        });


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-bind-html="message | emoji"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```